# IE8 does not support HTML5, but website is still rendered the same

Tags: html, ie8-compatibility-mode

I used http://www.html5test.com/ to check the compatibility of my Internet Explorer 8 browser.  There are various HTML elements that aren't supported.

I picked a HTML5 site (www.pusher.com) and inspect their elements.  The email address field in their homepage SignUp section still gets displayed.

I do not see any difference between Firefox 10.0.2 (which supports the 'email' input type) and IE8 (which does not support the 'email' input type).

I am a bit confused.  Is there a difference between HTML5 and old HTML in browsers?

I just picked up one element randomly. Any help and other examples are much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Old browsers such as IE8 treat all `<input>` elements as having a type of 'text' by default which is why it still works in IE8.

Additionally, the Pusher website you mentioned is using an [HTML5 shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) which helps IE to have compatibility with some HTML5 elements.

The relevant snippet:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```